# Implement Windows authentication in single page app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, single-page-application

I am trying to implement a single page application using MVC 5 and windows authentication.

Is it possible to implement SPA without login and using windows authentication?

Answer (score 0):

That it is an SPA App should have no impact on authentication - you would set up Windows Authentication as you would for any other mvc app.

start [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs)